# Hide share option from UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentinteraction

In my application I need to show some pdf files to the user. I'm using [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/) for this purpose:

```
.h
// Document interaction controller
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDocumentInteractionController *docViewer;

.m
_docViewer            = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
_docViewer.delegate   = self;
_docViewer.URL        = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"my file path"]];
[_docViewer presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

Everything works just fine. But the problem is I'm getting a share option in the document interaction controller.

[image: Doc Controller]

I don't want to show the share option in the document interaction controller. Is that possible ? I checked the class reference document and I didn't find any properties for hiding that option.

Comment: If am not wrong as I understood you want to remove the "Share" button from document interaction view controller. Am I right here?

Comment: @DharmeshSiddhpura: Yes, you are correct

Comment: as far as I looked you cannot hide or remove this share button from iOS 8. In iOS 7 I used QLPreviewController and then from its navigation controller I made rightBarButtonItem = nil. But now this is also not possible. I have removed my answer.

Comment: @DharmeshSiddhpura: Thanks for your valuable time and info :)

Answer (score 0):

may need to use a custom PDF Reader VC.
This one is updated a lot
https://github.com/vfr/Reader